# Why is selection.exit().size() zero?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to remove rect elements from an svg by joining an empty array to a d3 selection.

It's not working.

Presumably I've misunderstood something.

The code snippet below sets up the svg. When you press the "clear" button nothing happens.

I have 3 questions ( also marked in the code comments ) ;

1. Why does the selection not report size 4 after joining 4 data items and creating 4 associated elements ?
2. In the clearSVG function, why is the exit() size 0 after joining "no" data to the existing selection.
3. Why are the rects not removed ( probably answered in Q2 ).

```js
function init(){
    let initialData = [
        {x:0,y:0,c:"black"},
        {x:0,y:90,c:"orange"},
        {x:90,y:0,c:"green"},
        {x:90,y:90,c:"yellow"}        
    ];
    
    let nodes = d3.select("#svg").selectAll("dataNode") ;
            
    //console.log(`empty nodes size: ${nodes.size()}  all good .. ?`);      // reports 0  
    
    nodes    
    .data(initialData)
    .enter()
    .append(`svg:rect`)
    .attr("class", `dataNode`)
    .attr("x", function(d){return d.x;})
    .attr("y", function(d){return d.y;})     
    .attr("width", 10)
    .attr("height", 10)      
    .attr("fill", function(d){return d.c;}) ;
    
    //console.log(`initial data nodes size: ${nodes.size()} - Q1. why is this not 4 ?`); //reports 0
   
};

function clearSVG(){
    let nodes = d3.select("#svg").selectAll(".dataNode"); // all 4 rect elements in the svg
    //console.log(`nodes size: ${nodes.size()}`);// looking good.. 4 nodes reported
    let newData = [] ; // nada, no data 
    nodes.data(newData) ; // join nothing to the rects - no datum for any element in the selection
    //console.log(`exit size: ${nodes.exit().size()} - Q2. Why is this 0 and not 4 ?`);
    nodes.exit().remove();    
    //console.log(`Q3. Why are the rects still present ?`);
};


init();
```

```css
*{
    border:none;
    padding:0;       
    font-family:Arial;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
body{
    margin:10px;
}
#svg{
    display: inline-block ;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;

}
#plotBackGround{
    fill: #FBFBFB;  
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg id="svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100" >
   <rect id="plotBackGround" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100"></rect>
</svg>                           
    
<BR><BR>
       
<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="clearSVG();">Clear</button>
```

**Edit**

To summarise the crux of the accepted answer ; 
selection.data(), .enter(), .append(), .exit() and .remove() return ***new*** selections. They do ***not*** modify the selection they are called on or return a ref to it or its parts.

**End edit**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Problem

The problem here is quite straightforward: you don't have the correct update selection.

Let's see. You first do this:

```
let nodes = d3.select("#svg").selectAll(".dataNode");
```

Then, you change the data:

```
let newData = [];
nodes.data(newData);
```

However, you are not changing `nodes`, which remain as they were. When you later do:

```
nodes.exit().remove();
```

You're in fact just doing this:

```
d3.select("#svg").selectAll(".dataNode").exit().remove();
```

Which, as you can see, makes little sense.

#### Solution

Write the correct update selection. It should be:

```
nodes = nodes.data(newData);
```

Which, if we substitute the value of `nodes`, will give us effectively this:

```
d3.select("#svg").selectAll(".dataNode").data(newData).exit().remove();
```

Here is the code with that change only:

```js
function init(){
    let initialData = [
        {x:0,y:0,c:"black"},
        {x:0,y:90,c:"orange"},
        {x:90,y:0,c:"green"},
        {x:90,y:90,c:"yellow"}        
    ];
    
    let nodes = d3.select("#svg").selectAll("dataNode") ;
            
    //console.log(`empty nodes size: ${nodes.size()}  all good .. ?`);      // reports 0  
    
    nodes    
    .data(initialData)
    .enter()
    .append(`svg:rect`)
    .attr("class", `dataNode`)
    .attr("x", function(d){return d.x;})
    .attr("y", function(d){return d.y;})     
    .attr("width", 10)
    .attr("height", 10)      
    .attr("fill", function(d){return d.c;}) ;
    
    //console.log(`initial data nodes size: ${nodes.size()} - Q1. why is this not 4 ?`); //reports 0
   
};

function clearSVG(){
    let nodes = d3.select("#svg").selectAll(".dataNode"); // all 4 rect elements in the svg
    //console.log(`nodes size: ${nodes.size()}`);// looking good.. 4 nodes reported
    let newData = [] ; // nada, no data 
    nodes = nodes.data(newData) ; // join nothing to the rects - no datum for any element in the selection
    //console.log(`exit size: ${nodes.exit().size()} - Q2. Why is this 0 and not 4 ?`);
    nodes.exit().remove();    
    //console.log(`Q3. Why are the rects still present ?`);
};


init();
```

```css
*{
    border:none;
    padding:0;       
    font-family:Arial;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
body{
    margin:10px;
}
#svg{
    display: inline-block ;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;

}
#plotBackGround{
    fill: #FBFBFB;  
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg id="svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100" >
   <rect id="plotBackGround" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100"></rect>
</svg>                           
    
<BR><BR>
       
<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="clearSVG();">Clear</button>
```

Comment: this is btw also the reason as for why the `console.log` prints 0 (his first question)

Comment: @JanWendland Yes, the three questions in OP's list are actually just one problem.

Comment: @Bob Yes, I removed that example, since I didn't make clear what methods make changes in-place.